# Is long defined by system architecture, or is it an IEEE standard?

Tags: communication, 32bit-64bit, cpu-architecture, ieee

Working on getting some communication of longs between computers and chips. Was running into some issues and thought it might be because the definition of longs between different system architectures (We're talking between 32-bit and 64-bit machines). Does anyone know if longs are an IEEE standard (like floats and doubles), or if they vary based on system architecture? (like ints)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type long is not an IEEE standard. It's size may vary between different architectures. In C you can use the header stdint.h that defines types like uint32_t uint16_t etc that have fixed size. If your chip has a own C compiler that should solve your problem.